# IONIC 2 - Runtime Error. Cannot find module “ionic-native”

Tags: ionic2

I'm receiving this error while executing ionic 2 :

Error

> Runtime Error. Cannot find module “ionic-native”.

Stack

> g@localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7138
>   localhost:8100/build/main.js:113219:16
>   webpack_require@localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:34
>   localhost:8100/build/main.js:87074:92
>   webpack_require@localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:34
>   localhost:8100/build/main.js:135215:89
>   webpack_require@localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:34
>   localhost:8100/build/main.js:66:37 global
>   code@localhost:8100/build/main.js:67:12

Comment: can you add your package.json?

Comment: Did you install it with npm install @ionic-native/core --save

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install below

npm install ionic-native --save

Comment: npm install @ionic-native/core --save

Comment: You can refer below URL for the error  https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/README.md

Comment: no longer works. Wish they would stop making changes which break projects and make all the documentation completely useless.

Comment: not working properly above error is resolve but got another error :Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'. Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.?

Answer (score 4):

Issue may be because of ionic package up-gradation. Delete node_modules folder.

The ionic packages are changed from ionic 2.x to 3.x. You need to do following changes.

1. Delete reference of `ionic-native` from `package.json`.
2. Install ionic 3.x native packages using following commands

> npm install @ionic-native/core --save
>
> npm install @ionic-native/splash-screen --save
>
> npm install @ionic-native/@ionic-native/status-bar --save

3. Change references of ionic 2.x native package from `app.module.ts`.

> import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
>
> import {StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

4. Add `StatusBar` and `SplashScreen` in providers array of  `app.module.ts`
5. Update imports of `StatusBar` and `SplashScreen` in `app.component.ts` ( Just like step no. 3)
6. Add  following in constructor of  `app.component.ts`

> statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen

7. If you are using `http` service, import it in `app.module.ts` as below:

> import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

Add `HttpModule` in imports array.

Note: You may need to do same thing for the other similar native packages.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to install `Ionic Native` in your project:

```
npm install @ionic-native --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that error changing this:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/umd'
```

to this:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'
```